# How to make 20 minutes (1 day) delay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am getting tired of manually managing my chicken farm, so I have invented this automated design:

[image: image description]

The step from eggs to chicken is easy, and it's even simple to make it happen in batches - every time dispensers are filled using hoppers, a comparator activates clock until they're empty again.

What I need is to set up is a timeout that activates **20 minutes after the dispensers have stopped shooting**. A minecraft day has 20 minutes, which brings the idea of daylight sensor. But note that timeout may start any time in the day, not the same time every day.

And please, I need something that is not bigger than my house.

[image: image description]

Comment: Could do a daylight sensor, inverted, with a monostable circuit. I can get a proper answer complete with a screenshot in a bit

Comment: I am very curious!

Comment: Actually, hang on, that would be 10 minutes... And not play nice with sleeping. Hrm.

Comment: Hopper timers are the thing

Comment: @BlaXpirit I don't know if you could get one for 20 minutes though

Comment: Upvoted for awesome drawing!

Comment: I know Hypixel has used minecarts falling down cobwebs onto detector rails to create a delay. I'm not sure how tall the cobweb tower would need to be for 20 minutes and how to make it that exact, but that sort of mechanism should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could accomplish this with 2 hopper clocks chained together.

In 20 minutes there are 24000 game ticks, and an item takes 8 game ticks to transfer from one hopper to another. This means that the wait you want is the same time that it would take 3000 items to transfer.

A single hopper clock only works with up to 320 items, but are able to chain multiple hopper clocks together to multiply the delay:

[image: Hopper clock diagram]

The second hopper clock can only transfer an item when the first hopper clock activates. If you put 10 items in the first hopper clock like this:

[image: 10 items in a hopper GUI]

Then 300 items in the second hopper clock:

[image: 300 items in a hopper GUI]

Then the first hopper clock needs to activate 300 times to activate the second hopper clock and get the output. 300 * 10 = 3000, so the second hopper clock should activate after 20 minutes.

This can all fit within 6*6:

[image: Chained hopper clocks within 6 by 6 area]

You can stop the clock by keeping powered one hopper in both of the hopper clocks, you should probably turn it on after the dispensers have fired then back off after the trapdoors have opened. You should be able to get the output pulse (it'll be inverted) from the wire on the right.

Comment: Other ways of achieving this is: cobweb chain, repeater chain, timer based on baby animals growing up and hit box changing.

Comment: @ModDL have examples of these? I'd love to see other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Or another option: a despawn clock. Items take exactly 5 minutes to despawn. So you can use 4 droppers and 4 wooden pressure plates as your timer (because 4*5=20, obviously). Each pressure plate is on a block with a redstone torch under it. When the dropper spits an item out, it turns off the torch for exactly 5 minutes, then turns it back on. You can use this to trigger the next dropper in the series. After this occurs 4 times, the last output is your clock output.