# Delay redstone with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to use commands to make a long delay? I do not want to use a dispenser to fire an arrow into a button, because I don't want to keep reloading it, nor do I want to use a lot of repeaters. Can anyone help with possible commands/layouts for this sort of idea?

Comment: This is possible, though there are better solutions, like a [hopper clock](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221602/20306)

Comment: As I said in my question, I want to use commands

Comment: Also, why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a scoreboard timer starting with the number of seconds you want to count down. Something like this:

Start by setting up the scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
```

Next you will want to put a clock with 2 command blocks. Choose the command block that triggers first and put this in it:

```
/scoreboard players remove TimerEntity timer 1
```

The other command block should have this command:

```
/scoreboard players test TimerEntity timer -5 0
```

Put a comparator leading out of that block with the commands you want to execute, or redstone, along with the final command block with:

```
/scoreboard players set TimerEntity timer {delay}
```

Comment: I suggest using 1.9's repeat/chain command blocks and the *conditional* setting rather than comparators here.

Answer (score -2):

A very simple way to do this is simply with a /wait command. It's really just /wait [time in redstone ticks], at 20 ticks per second. At the end of that time, it will send a pulse out to any comparators attached to it, which you can use to power your dispensers (the pulse is the same as clicking a button.) Any other redstone put through it in that time would be outputted at the end of that time stacking on top of what's already coming. If you wanted it to loop, you could just put another string of redstone out from the string going into the dispenser to loop back around to the command block, and put a few repeaters on it so the pulse is over by the time it gets there. Hope this helped!

Comment: `/wait` is not a vanilla command. You should specify what mods/plugins/software is being used.

Comment: @user Please don't make stuff up. Or at least say it's a MOD that has this command